# Credit card fields in facebook page

Tags: facebook, paypal, shopping-cart

Am I allowed to have payment methods inside a facebook page ? 
I'm using an iframe to integrate a shopping cart into a facebook page. 
The shopping cart is PCI compliant and safe. But I just don't know if facebook would allow this in one of their pages, considering that it uses other payment methods except facebook credits.

Payment methods inside cart :
mastercard/visa, american express, paypal, bank/wire transfer, etc